# Filter time in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a column where there is only time. After reading that CSV file i have converted that column to datetime datatype as it was object when i read it in jupyter notebook. When i try to filter i am getting error like below

```
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

code

```
newdata = newdata['APPOINTMENT_TIME'].between_time('14:30:00', '20:00:00')
```

sample_data

```
APPOINTMENT_TIME Id
13:30:00    1
15:10:00    2
18:50:00    3
14:10:00    4
14:00:00    5
```

Here i am trying display the rows whose appointment_time is between 14:30:00 to 20:00:00
[datatype info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvjJB.png)

Could anyone help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`between_time` is a special method that works with datetime objects as index, which is not your case. It would be useful if you had data like `2021-12-21 13:30:00`

In your case, you can just use the `between` method on strings and the fact that times with your format `HH:MM:SS` will be naturally sorted:

```
filtered_data = newdata[newdata['APPOINTMENT_TIME'].between('14:30:00', '20:00:00')]
```

Output:

```
  APPOINTMENT_TIME  Id
1         15:10:00   2
2         18:50:00   3
```

*NB. You can't use a range that starts before midnight and ends after.*

Comment: I tried you code and getting the error```TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'``` . the dtype of that column is object. could you help?

Comment: Rather looks like you have a datetime (or mixed) type. Can you provide a reproducible dataframe with the correct types?

Comment: i have added in the main question about the datatype. could you please check

Comment: Check your column, you probably have mixed types of datetime and something else (None, string...). One (dirty) option is to use `newdata['APPOINTMENT_TIME'].astype(str).between(...)` but better figure out what's going on with the data.